# Array transformation/manipulation

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, lodash

I have one array like this one:

```
array1=[{value:1, label:'value1'},{value:2, label:'value2'}, {value:3, label:'value3'}]
```

I have a second array of integer :

```
array2=[1,3]
```

I would like to obtain this array without a loop for :

```
arrayResult = ['value1', 'value3']
```

Does someone know how to do it with javascript ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: What is the point of your value field in array1? is it always the index + 1? If so, you do not need it and could just have array1 = ['value1', 'value2', ...]

Comment: Description doesn't indicate what array2 represents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map the elements in `array2` to the `label` property of the element in `array1` with the corresponding `value`:

```
array2                      // Take array2 and
  .map(                     // map
    function(n) {           // each element n in it to
      return array1         // the result of taking array1
        .find(              // and finding
          function(e) {     // elements
            return          // for which 
              e.value       // the value property
              ===           // is the same as 
              n;            // the element from array2
          }
        )
        .label              // and taking the label property of that elt
      ;
    }
  )
;
```

Without comments, and in ES6:

```
array.map(n => array1.find(e => e.value === n).label);
```

Comment: @bokzor Note `.find` is new method and it is not supported in IE, https://goo.gl/blSYko

Comment: Yes. But I prefer the first one. But thanks anyway :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), like this

```js
var array1 = [
    {value:1, label:'value1'},{value:2, label:'value2'}, {value:3, label:'value3'}
];

var array2 = [1, 3];

var arrayResult = array1.filter(function (el) {
  return array2.indexOf(el.value) >= 0;
}).map(function (el) {
  return el.label;
});

console.log(arrayResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple [for-loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) should suffice for this. In the future you should seriously post some code to show what you have tried.

```
var array1=[{value:1, label:'value1'},{value:2, label:'value2'}, {value:3, label:'value3'}];
var array2=[1,3];
var result = [];

for (var i = 0; i < array2.length; i++){
  result.push(array1[array2[i]-1].label);
}
console.log(result); //["value1", "value3"]
```

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/xehecozuwo/edit?js,output)

Answer (score 0):

Good answers all. If I may suggest one more alternative using `Map` as this seems to be suited to a key:value pair solution.

```
var arr1 = [ {value:1, label:'value1'}, {value:2, label:'value2'}, {value:3, label:'value3'} ];
var arr2 = [1, 3];

// create a Map of the first array making value the key.
var map = new Map( arr1.map ( a => [a.value, a.label] ) );

// map second array with the values of the matching keys
var result = arr2.map( n => map.get ( n ) );
```

Of course this supposes that the key:value structure of the first array will not become more complex, and could be written in the simpler form of.

```
var arr1 = [[1,'value1'], [2,'value2'], [3,'value3']]; // no need for names
var arr2 = [1, 3];

var map = new Map( arr1 ); // no need to arr1.map ;
var result = arr2.map( n => map.get ( n ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Just index the first array using the _.indexBy function:

```
var indexedArray1 = _.indexBy(array1, "value");
_.map(array2, function(x) { return indexedArray1[x].label; });
```